# Read image from folder with PHP and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Hi guys thanks for read this. I'm trying to read several photos from a folder. In my table I got a field called "path" this is the name of the folder who im trying to call to list images so my code is [here](http://jsbin.com/ehezew/2/edit) (Sorry but i cant apply my code some validation errors):

```
<?
$conexion = mysql_connect("localhost","miuser","mipass") or die("Error al conectar a la BD");
$db = mysql_select_db("midb");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM fotos";
$obj = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error de query [".$sql."]");
?>
while($resultado = mysql_fetch_array($obj))
{
?>
<img width="210" height="138" src="images/media/<? echo $resultado["foto"];?>" />
}
?>
mysql_close($conexion);
?>
```

I try scandir but I couldn't get this HTML output format:

```
title 1 (folder1)
image1.jpg
image2.jpg
```

then the next folder

```
title 32 (folder32)
image1.jpg
image2.jpg
image3.jpg
image4.jpg
```

and then the another one folder

```
title 54 (folder54)
image4.jpg
image77.jpg
```

Like you see I need to list the images inside folder, one by one folder content.
So an example ill be : If folder 1 has 3 images inside, then the code should list this 3 images each one inside of a div. I hope this help :/

Comment: Your "code" is PHP yet pasted into a box for HTML ... thats not going to work ... can you show us your schema of the `fotos` table ... and some sample data

Comment: Please post your code in Stackoverflow not on another site.

Comment: Your example given is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I just use some code like this:

```
$directorio = "images/media/".$objResult["full"]; 
$images = scandir($directorio);
```

So thanks you to all :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function read_folder_directory($dir = "path")
    {
        $listDir = array();
        if($handler = opendir($dir)) {
            while (($sub = readdir($handler)) !== FALSE) {
                if ($sub != "." && $sub != ".." && $sub != "Thumb.db" && $sub != "Thumbs.db") {
                    if(is_file($dir."/".$sub)) {
                        $listDir[] = $sub;
                    }elseif(is_dir($dir."/".$sub)){
                        $listDir[$sub] = ReadFolderDirectory($dir."/".$sub);
                    }
                }
            }
            closedir($handler);
        }
        return $listDir;
    }
?>
```

Using:

```
<?php
$files = read_folder_directory ();

if ($files)
{
     foreach ($files as $file)
     {
           echo $file."<br/>"
     }
}
?>
```

look in the examples - http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php

Comment: @roselan Thanks for that example i make some modification in my example http://jsbin.com/ehezew/2/edit i got some errores but now its fine thanks for all your help guys!

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM fotos";
$previousDirName = false;
$obj = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error de query [".$sql."]");
while($resultado = mysql_fetch_array($obj)) {
  $dirName = pathinfo($resultado["foto"], PATHINFO_DIRNAME);
  if ( $dirName != $previousDirName ) {
    if ( $previousDirName ) { ?></div><? } 
    ?><div><div class="path"><? echo $dirName ?></div><?
  }
  ?><div class="photo"><img width="210" height="138" src="images/media/<? echo pathinfo($resultado["foto"], PATHINFO_BASENAME);?>" /></div><?
  $previousDirName = $dirName;
}
?></div><? // closes last path div
}

mysql_close($conexion);
?>
```

this assumes that "foto" field is the full path, and not the file name only.